# Converting Esri Leaflet featureCollection to JSON?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, esri-leaflet, query-task

I've followed the Esri Leaflet sample code found here:

http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/tasks/query.html

```
//Querying features near a latlng
var latlng = L.latLng(45.51, -122.70);

var query = L.esri.Tasks.query({
            url:'http://services.arcgis.com/rOo16HdIMeOBI4Mb/arcgis/rest/services/stops/FeatureServer/0'
});

query.nearby(latlng, 500);

query.run(function(error, featureCollection, response){
console.log('Found ' + featureCollection.features.length + ' features');
});
```

So now that I have the features any Idea of how to export them out as JSON or GeoJSON? I need them as input for another app.  So far the only thing I found you could do is count them.

Answer (score 1):

The feature collection **is** GeoJSON:

```javascript
var myGeoJSON = JSON.stringify(featureCollection)
console.log(myGeoJSON)
```

Comment: Thank You, simple answer that works, I did try to parse JSON on it but that failed, so close but....  Thanks...